# Visualizing DBSCAN in maps for Python

Tags: geolocation, google-visualization, dbscan

i have run a DBSCAN model to cluster geo data points, that is, latitude and longitud. To set the parameter i want to have a visual input as to how the clusters look in the map.

How can i achieve this? Also, in a form that wont crash my computer. For example, drawing 800 K points using gmaps tends to slow my computer significantly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tools such as ELKI allow you to draw **convex hulls** and **alpha shapes** of clusters. These are a lot simpler than the raw data, and easier to interpret.

See e.g. https://doublebyteblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/visualizing-micro-blogging-data/

Comment: Any tips on how to use this tools in Python. They seem to be compile in Java, but not sure how tu use them from python

Comment: I used them from Java. I don't see a benefit of wrapping that into fake Python. Just use `subprocess` module to run Java, then read the output file if you want to continue in Python.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure you can also compute convex hulls and alpha shapes in Python. But you may need to write more code yourself. I am just saying that convex hulls apparently work well for this (see the link above).